# React-Select: How to Add a Custom ClassName for Each Option of Dropdown?

Tags: puppeteer, react-select

I want to add a custom class name in each **option** of **React-select dropdown**. Later, to use that class name as the reference and click with **Puppeteer** for an end to end testing.

Right now when I click on drop-down, it has dynamic classes and when want to debug the HTML structure, dropdown closes and HTML also disappears.

The code is as follows:

```
<Select
    options={this.loadSuppliers()}
    value={this.props.supplierPicker ? this.props.supplierPicker : []}
    defaultValue={
        this.state.SupplierId
    }
    isSearchable={true}
    onChange={this.onChangeSupplier}
    id="supplier"
    >
</Select>
```

supplierPick has JSON with value and label as keys.

Comment: Sorry it is not quite clear if you are asking: (1) how to add unique class names for `<option> ` tags in React; or (2) how can you prevent the dropdown to be closed so you can investigate the element in devtools. Can you clarify your question a bit? I cannot decide if you are waiting for a chrome-devtools or a React.Js answer 

Comment: Let's stick with ReactJS.